# Prevent Form submitting and hitting keyup event handler not working

Tags: javascript, forms, events, submit, keypress

Having some problem cross browser. I need to Support IE7-9, my site is set to IE7 standards - cannot be changed. Then i need to support latest chrome, safari and firefox.

I want to hit a keyup event in a textbox on enter. Problem is i have a keypress event added to the form on that page which is submitting the form which i dont want to happen.
Sample application would be like this.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").bind("keypress", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {
                $("#log1").append("Key press - Form event");
            }                
        });

        $("#myInput1").bind("keypress", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code != 13) {
                return true;
            }

            $("#log2").append("Enter pressed - input event");

            //if (!e) var e = window.event;

            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                //e.preventDefault();
            }

        });

        $("#myInput1").bind("keyup", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code != 13) {
                return true;
            }

            $("#log1").append("Key up - Enter pressed - input event");
        });


    });​
```

**HTML**

```
<li onkeypress="alert('hi')">
            <input id="myInput1" type="text" />
            <div id="log1"></div>
            <div id="log2"></div>
        </li>
```

If i use e.preventDefault() - keyup event is not hit, if i dont use it, page is posting back.

I want to see "Key up - Enter pressed - input event" to be written to screen on pressing enter, across all browsers.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is trouble `if (!e) var e = window.event;`

Comment: @elclanrs I can remove that, no issues, and i think that line of code will never be hit.

Comment: Did you try $('form').on('submit', function(){return false;})

Comment: And yes, the line `if (!e) var e = window.event;` is totally redundant

Comment: @DimaBildin i dont have much liberty to touch that event. I can do anything in my textbox control. and we are using jquery 1.5

Comment: Why do you have both a `keyup` and `keypress` handler on the same input? Also, if you're using jQuery (as you seem to be) it normalises `e.which` so you don't need to test for `e.keyCode`. Similarly, you can be assured that jQuery provides `e.stopPropagation()` so you don't have to test for it and don't need to worry about `e.cancelBubble()` or `e.returnValue` and don't have to worry about `window.event`. If you're having problems, first remove all this unnecessary code and then debug what is left.

Comment: @nnnnnn i can remove keypress, i dont have any issues in that, but how can i make my keyup event to trigger on that textbox without form being submitted. That is the actual issue!

Comment: I think you'll find the form is submitted on key _down,_ so it is too late to prevent it in the key _up_ handler.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").bind("keypress", function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            $("#log1").append("Key press - Form event");
        }                
    });


        $("#myInput1").bind("keypress", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (e.keyCode != 13) {
                return true;
            }

            $("#log2").append("Enter pressed - input event");


            e.stopPropagation();
            sampleE = e.keyCode;
           $("#myInput1").trigger("keyup");
           return false;
        });

        $("#myInput1").bind("keyup", function (e) {
            if (!e.keyCode)
                e.keyCode = sampleE;
            if (e.keyCode != 13) {
                return true;
            }

            $("#log1").append("Key up - Enter pressed - input event");
        });


    });
    var sampleE = null;
```

I know this is not the best of the options but this is working. Thanks All.